# current directory changes in admin mode (Windows Batch file)

Tags: windows, batch-file

MY code contains following line of code

`diskpart/s %CD%\script.txt 
ECHO %CD%`
when i run it normally it works fine

but when i use "run as administrator" %CD%  returns C:\Windows>cd System32
so  my file (script.txt)  is not found there and my code fails at this point

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
diskpart/s %~dp0script.txt 
ECHO %~dp0
```